# How to set focus on other application based on process name VB

Tags: vb.net, process, focus

How can I set focus on other application based on process name in VB2010?

What I can do now is set focus on other application based on windows name using FindWindow then use SetForegroundWindow. Below is what I currently have

```
        Dim theHandle As IntPtr
        theHandle = FindWindow(Nothing, "Gmail: Email from Google")
        If theHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        SetForegroundWindow(theHandle)
```

The problem is that FindWindow need exact windows name to works and I don't always know the exact name. (Because my program open up different website that the user enter, so I have no control over they site they open). So is there anyway that I can set focus using the process name instead? (in this case firefox.exe)  Any other suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to look up a process by name and then find the window title:

```
For Each app As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")
    Dim theHandle As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, app.MainWindowTitle)
    If theHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        SetForegroundWindow(theHandle)
    End If
Next
```

Use the static `GetProcessesByName` method and then the `MainWindowTitle` property.  For this sample you would need `Import System.Diagnostics` to import the right namespace.

Comment: Please forgive the syntax if it's off; I don't have VB Express installed on this PC.

Comment: Incredibly fragile; better hope they don't change the name! It's already happened once.

Comment: @Cody I can't disagree.  However, the OP asked how to set focus based on process name.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ActivateApp(ByVal pID As Integer)
        Dim p As Process = Process.GetProcessById(pID)
        If p IsNot Nothing Then
            SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Then use this:

```
ActivateApp(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.Id)
SendKeys.SendWait("~")
```